# Should I replace amissing insulation over the heat tape on my water pipes?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, pipe

I recently moved into a mobile home and with the temperature dropping below freezing I wanted to make sure my water line was protected.  It has a electric heat tape wrapped around it with insulation.  A short, 3-4", section of the insulation wrap is missing.  Should I be concerned about missing a short piece or will the heat wrap still keep the water warm enough to prevent freezing.  The skirt is in place under the home.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to know, as there are so many variables (water temperature, usage; air temperature, wind; etc). Sounds like you'd at least feel more secure if you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to DIY! You should replace the missing piece of insulation. The insulation works with the heat tape to prevent freezing.